# Drupal Image Display with View and Panels

Tags: image, drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-panels

Can anyone please guide me on how do I create a photobox that contains image and I wanted to display that image on landing page. 
I have used panel to create landing pages for my website. I need to create 7 different layout for my website.
I am new to Drupal. Any help will be appreciated.

I have created specific image style for my image box by going into "Configuration -> Image Styles.

I have created Content Types for image.

For example lets say, Content type is: "Top Left Image".
I have defined fields called "Image Name" and "Image" into "Top Left Image".

Then I have created one view called " Top Left Imagebox".
In view, I have defined fields called Content: Image.

Formatter: Image
Image Style: Selected specific image style.
Link Image to: Nothing

I have used Rewrite Rule to make a view that displays image or video filed if present.

No Results Behavior: [field_image]
Checked - Hide rewriting if empty
Checked Rewrite the output of this field.

I have defined this view into my Landing Panel Page. But, somehow **image is not displaying into the browser.**

**Thanks for Help!!**

Comment: How does your view know which 'top left image' to show? Do you get a result in the views ui preview? If you are only going to have 1 'top left image', it would be better to put this into a block.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because your ad blocker block your images. Anything that comes with names like 'ad' will be blocked be ad blocker browser add-ons.

Try switching it off if you have any enabled.

This is my best guess if you have your images in your view & you have added that view into your panel page.